# Pair Varargs input with one element of fixed type

Tags: julia

I can construct the following:

```
foo(p::Pair...) = dostuff
```

This will work for a list of pairs. I would like to do the following:

```
foo{N}(p::Pair{Symbol,N}...) = dostuff
```

where the first entry of each pair is a Symbol, but the second entry is unconstrained. The construction above requires that all 2nd entries are of the same type, but I want to allow any 2nd entry:

```
foo(:a=>1, :b=>"hi")
```

Is there a way to do this?
Do I need to just go with the first version and enforce the argument type in the function itself and throw an error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since parametric types with unspecified trailing type parameters are treated as abstract supertypes, matching the specified types, the type `Pair{Symbol}` matches any pair with first parameter being `Symbol` with any second parameter. Thus, you can write the method signature you want like this way:

```
foo(p::Pair{Symbol}...) = "pairs from symbols"
```

This doesn't help if you want to dispatch on the second type parameter but not the first. To accomplish that, you need a type alias:

```
typealias Riap{B,A} Pair{A,B}

foo(p::Riap{Symbol}...) = "pairs to symbols"
```

We can see these two methods in action:

```
julia> foo(:a => 1.5, :b => "x")
"pairs from symbols"

julia> foo(1.5 => :a, "x" => :b)
"pairs to symbols"

julia> foo(:a => :b, :c => :d)
ERROR: MethodError: foo(::Pair{Symbol,Symbol}, ::Pair{Symbol,Symbol}) is ambiguous. Candidates:
  foo(p::Pair{A<:Any,Symbol}...) at REPL[5]:1
  foo(p::Pair{Symbol,B<:Any}...) at REPL[1]:1
 in eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:231
 in macro expansion at ./REPL.jl:92 [inlined]
 in (::Base.REPL.##1#2{Base.REPL.REPLBackend})() at ./event.jl:46

julia> foo()
ERROR: MethodError: foo( is ambiguous. Candidates:
  foo(p::Pair{A<:Any,Symbol}...) at REPL[5]:1
  foo(p::Pair{Symbol,B<:Any}...) at REPL[1]:1
 in eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:231
 in macro expansion at ./REPL.jl:92 [inlined]
 in (::Base.REPL.##1#2{Base.REPL.REPLBackend})() at ./event.jl:46
```